# TCPDF User Units

Tags: tcpdf

I'm having a strange behaviour of the user units in TCPDF.

I created a new PDF with the following construct:

```
$pdf = new Pdf("P", "mm", "A4", true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

The strange thing is that getPageDimensions() is getting me strange user units:

```
$pageDimensions = $this->getPageDimensions();
$pageDimensions['wk']: 50.4000346667
$pageDimensions['hk']: 71.28002
$this->getPageWidth(): 50.4000346667
$this->getPageHeight(): 71.28002
```

I cannot understand what's wrong.
Could you help me, please?

Thank you very much!
Bye.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered and solved my problem.
I my custom class (which extends TCPDF) I was redeclaring and so rewriting the value of the "dpi" variable.